# how to separate 3 different groups of y in a simple linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

The data has a variable charges- cost of insurance and age - that is the age of the individual.
I am trying to predict charges (y) from age and am using R.
This is the scatterplot I am getting:

[image: scatterplot between charges and age]

my code for the model is :

```
plot_age<- ggplot( train, aes(x = age, y = charges)) + geom_point()
```

and the summary is:

[image: summary]

I am clearly able to see 3 different groups. Is there a way to make this model better?

I tried to separate closer age groups such as group together ages between 19 and 23, 35-40, etc. but I realized that this wouldn't work as every separate "group" has all the age groups.

Comment: Your data is separating over the outcome variable, not the predictor variable. There is likely another variable than age that can explain for this difference. Maybe bin your charges variable in 3 categories, less than 15000, 15000 to 25000, and 25000+ and then crosstab across other variables to see what variable is associated with that breakdown

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have data like this (which I quickly simulated).

```
> str(dat[-3])
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ age      : num  61 62 31 57 48 42 53 24 49 51 ...
 $ insurance: num  14786 1225 32650 2500 2043 ...
 $ charges  : num  28788 15386 37445 14885 11375 ...
```

I'm not sure why you don't add *insurance* to your model; as you noticed, *charges* are obviously divided in three groups, and usually insurances group us into different say risk groups. Also *age* appears to have the usual slight `poly`nomial influence.

The `AIC` guides you which model provides the best prediction, the less the better.

```
with(dat, plot(age, charges, pch=20, panel.first=grid()))
```

[image]

```
> summary(f1 <- lm(charges ~ age, dat))$coe
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 5449.9211 1196.10223  4.556401 5.847361e-06
age          280.2991   27.71355 10.114154 5.845383e-23
> AIC(f1)
[1] 21627.12


> summary(f2 <- lm(charges ~ age + insurance, dat))$coe
                Estimate   Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -3787.917643 43.898173262 -86.28873        0
age           281.664438  0.987983633 285.09019        0
insurance       0.997996  0.001126929 885.58929        0
> AIC(f2)
[1] 14960.09


> summary(f3 <- lm(charges ~ poly(age, 2, raw=TRUE) + insurance, dat))$coe
                            Estimate   Std. Error      t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)               14.9137452 2.997296e+01    0.4975734  6.188946e-01
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)1 74.0177212 1.558792e+00   47.4840371 4.450037e-258
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)2  2.5117835 1.865728e-02  134.6275210  0.000000e+00
insurance                  0.9998817 2.577128e-04 3879.8292711  0.000000e+00
> AIC(f3)
[1] 12007.32
```

If you already tried *insurance*, and it's rather random noise,

```
> summary(f4 <- lm(charges ~ poly(age, 2, raw=TRUE) + insurance2, dat))$coe
                             Estimate  Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)               3335.384722 3682.377581  0.9057693 0.36527701
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)1  395.941773  191.300209  2.0697404 0.03873402
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)2   -1.400207    2.289572 -0.6115584 0.54096952
insurance2                -338.126051  377.836133 -0.8949013 0.37105605
> AIC(f4)
[1] 21629.93
```

you could try to perform `kmeans`-clustering.

```
set.seed(42)
cl <- as.factor(kmeans(as.matrix(dat$charges), 3)$cl)

with(dat, plot(age, charges, pch=20, panel.first=grid(), col=cl))
legend('topleft', leg=sort(unique(cl)), col=sort(unique(cl)), 
       title='k-means cluster', pch=20, horiz=TRUE, cex=.9)
```

[image]

```
> summary(f5 <- lm(charges ~ poly(age, 2, raw=TRUE) + relevel(cl, 2), dat))$coe
                              Estimate   Std. Error    t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)               -8104.288947 1071.6690371  -7.562306  8.984321e-14
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)1   726.056149   55.6745999  13.041066  5.311684e-36
poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)2    -7.388479    0.6818584 -10.835797  6.122137e-26
relevel(cl, 2)1           31740.604031  292.4633604 108.528480  0.000000e+00
relevel(cl, 2)3           10561.462117  287.9908463  36.672909 5.807241e-187
> AIC(f5)
[1] 19079.8
```

Cluster *2* was `relevel`ed as `ref=`erence cluster (see plot).

---

*Simulated data:*

```
n <- 1e3
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(age=round(runif(n, 18, 65)),
                  group=as.factor(sample(3, n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(8/12, 2/12, 2/12))))  ## risk group
dat <- transform(dat, 
          insurance=ifelse(group == 1, runif(n, 1e2, 2.5e3) + rnorm(n, 100, 200), 
                                ifelse(group == 2, runif(n, 1.25e4, 1.75e4) + rnorm(n, 0, 2e3),
                                       runif(n, 3.25e4, 3.35e4) + rnorm(n, 1, 3e3))),
          insurance2=rnorm(n))  ## random noise insurance
dat <- transform(dat, charges=0 + insurance + 75*age + 2.5*age^2 + rnorm(n, 0, 1e2))
dat$group <- NULL  ## we don't know the group
```